# Can not Import module from different package in monkeyrunner

Tags: python, import, module, monkeyrunner

I want to import a module Devices.py from package abc.devices, but it gives me an import error : No Module named abc. Here dev is a one package in which contains the module Devices.py. below is the code of my monkeyrunner file.

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import unittest
import commands
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser
from abc.Devices import Devices
dev = Devices()
dev.gDevice()

from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyDevice, MonkeyRunner, MonkeyImage
from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient, View
```

Comment: you might want to search keyword **PYTHONPATH**

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have add the package in the PYTHONPATH but its not working. I don't know why this is so. When I am running this file with python interpreter there is no error, but when i am running with monkeyrunner it shows me an error.

Comment: sorry, monkeyrunner is new to me, +1 for the knowledge

Comment: you can add viewclient.py to /sdk/tools/lib/Lib folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

monlyrunner is not reading PYTHONPATH so you have to do this before importing your modules (as ViewClient's examples do):

```
# PyDev sets PYTHONPATH, use it
try:
    for p in os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(':'):
        if not p in sys.path:
            sys.path.append(p)
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but actually i have a created a script file which checks the envrionment variables PYTHONPATH and ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME. When i am importing this file from the same package in which my .mr files are there it is not showing me an error but when I am moving this file to other package it shows me an import error: no module named abc

Comment: Does it matter what Python version is installed (2 or 3)?